# replace lines between two lines in a template file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file with the following content:

```js
function(doc) {
  //pr reqs
  var facet = true;
  var store = true;
  // Template start
  var fields = {

  }
  // template end

  noiseList = ["type", "objects", "value"]

  const isNumeric = (num) => {
    return !isNaN(num)
  }

  const emitIndex = () => {
    if (doc.created_by_ref) {
      Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(key) {
        if (typeof fields[key] == 'object' && fields[key].length !== undefined) {
          if (fields[key].length === 0) {
            index(key, 'UNDEFINED', {
              'store': store,
              'facet': facet
            });
          } else {
            fields[key].forEach(function(ele) {
              index(key, ele.toString(), {
                'store': store,
                'facet': facet
              });
            })
          }
        } else {
          index(key, fields[key].toString(), {
            'store': store,
            'facet': facet
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }

  Object.keys(doc).map(obj => {
    if (typeof doc[obj] === 'object' && doc[obj] !== null) {
      traverseObjectsInDoc(doc[obj], noiseCancelation(obj) ? "" : obj, doc.objects, false);
    } else if (doc[obj] !== null && isValueType(obj) && !noiseCancelation(obj)) {
      AddToFields(`${obj}`, doc[obj])
    }
  });

  emitIndex();
}
```

As you I have two special sign there: template start and template end
what I am trying to achieve is to replace sth similar to

```js
var fields = {
  "test1": "test",
  "test2": "test2"
}
```

instead of

```js
var fields = {

}
```

in that file. And I should mention that this fields are generated in runtime so the content needs to be dynamic as well that is why I need this approach. All I can think of is to read the file

```
const searchAll1 = () => {
  const contents = fs
    .readFileSync("./lib/design_documents/searchAll", "utf8");
 // find the template end and start replace the new fields some and return
};
```

and find the template end and start replace the new fields somehow and return. However I am not really sure if this is the best way? 
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Could you explain why you are choosing this approach and what the end goal is? Because changing the file in an editor would be the easiest way. Otherwise give the function a second parameter in which you can pass the `fields` object.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier True but this file needs to be upgraded dynamically on the fly and the feilds are changing based on the different data sources

Comment: @EmielZuurbier my concern is more of my approach in replacing the fields. IS there any good way to replace a part of a template in a file?

Comment: Can I use regex for the above?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the design of your function by adding a second parameter you can add the `fields` object dynamically whenever you call the function.

```
// your-script.js
module.exports = function(doc, fields) {
  ...
}
```

Then when you import and use the function, create a new object and pass it to your function and call it.

```
const yourFunction = require('./your-script.js');

let doc = someValue;

let fields = {
  "test1": "test",
  "test2": "test2"
}

yourFunction(doc, fields);
```